# Parsing list of xml files in java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to write java code to parse list of xml files. How do I pass those list of xml files into parse method.

Code to parse file:

```
public void parseXml(String xmlPath, String tagName) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {
            DocumentBuilder docBuild = dbFact.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = docBuild.parse(xmlPath);
            NodeList nl = dom.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            System.out.println("Total tags: " + nl.getLength());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pe) {
            System.out.println(pe);
        }catch (SAXException se){
            System.out.println(se);
        }catch (IOException ie){
            System.out.println(ie);
        }

    }
```

Code to retrieve all xml files from directory:

```
public static List<File> getFiles(String path){
        File folder = new File(path);
        List<File> resultFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for(File file: listOfFiles){
            if(file.isFile() && file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xml")){
                resultFiles.add(file);
            }else if(file.isDirectory()){
                resultFiles.addAll(getFiles(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }

        return resultFiles;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filters

```
public static List<File> getFiles(String path) {
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml") && !name.toLowerCase().contains("settings_");
        }
    });

    return Arrays.asList(listOfFiles);
}
```

And modify your method to accept list of files

```
public void parseXml(List<File> xmlFiles, String tagName) {
    for (File xmlFile : xmlFiles) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFact = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder docBuild = dbFact.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = docBuild.parse(xmlFile);
            NodeList nl = dom.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
            System.out.println("Total tags: " + nl.getLength());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pe) {
            System.out.println(pe);
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            System.out.println(se);
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to pass this list of files into parse() method

Comment: `parseXml(getFiles("xmlPath"), "myXmlTag");`

Comment: What is the objective of your code? To count the occurrence of a tag in a set of xml files?

Comment: Syam, in my first code snippet I want to retrieve particular files from directory or sub directories and I want to ignore xml files named with settings_xxxx. Can you help me in this?

Comment: You could add any condition to filters. Updated my answer.